# jQuery to bind input value to span or div?

Tags: jquery

Please excuse me if this is a newbie question. I am new to this.

I would like that a user fill out a form with their info and, just before clicking submit, there to be a summary of details area where they confirm their details are correctly entered.

So is it possible for me to "bind" specific inputs to specific spans or divs and as they type (or maybe onBlur?) the span would reflect what is written in the respective input???

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Stack Overflow does something similar when you ask a question or write an answer. You should provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do. Show some markup, show us what you've tried so far and what hasn't worked. Be specific!

Answer (score 7):

Populate div with id `somediv` with whatever is typed the input with id `inputid` each time a key is pressed:

```
$('#inputid').keyup(function() {
    $('#somediv').html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myFormField').bind('change', function(){
 $('#myTargetSpan').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Two most obvious possibilities

1. Use jQuery [Data Link](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/data-link/) plug-in that is able to bind input elements to other elements or even to JavaScript objects. Either a one-way or a two-way link can be established.

   **or**
2. Use this code to update `div`

   *on each keystroke*

   ```
   $("#YourInputID").keyup(function(){
       $("#YourDivID").text(this.value);
   });
   ```

   *when user leaves input*

   ```
   $("#YourInputID").blur(function(){
       $("#YourDivID").text(this.value);
   });
   ```